# Azure - WebApp - authenticate requests by certificate

Tags: azure, authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I would like to use certificate authentication for requests on my website. But when I set clientCertEnabled to true (through https://resources.azure.com/) I am getting 403 forbidden error when I try to reach my site through https.

Through browser I get blue screen Error 403 - This web app is stopped but I can still access web site through http. When I switch clientCertEnabled back to false https is working.

Through fiddler I get 403 as well (client certificate is included in request) with no additional info.

I followed this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth/ but there is nothing else mentioned to be required to make this work.

Do I have to upload client certificates somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found out that problem was in my client certificate which I was using for testing.

Certificate generated in a way described in this very useful blog post worked properly:

https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/14/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-2-creating-self-signed-client-certificates/

Comment: what is the problem? I'm using public cert (p7b) provided by my client partner but i'm having the same problem. If i'm using my own self generating certificate(p7x) that contains private key, it's working. Please share your solution.